# How do I access the raw (or full) X509 Certificate in a Node.js web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, x509certificate, x509

Given a simple Node.js app:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('mykey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('mycert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.connection.getPeerCertificate());
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Results in output to the console with a *representation* of the certificate, not the original (PEM) format.

Are there other methods available to access the original?

Answer (score 1):

The certificate object returned by `getPeerCertificate` has a `raw` field holding the DER encoding of the certificate.

You can work with this DER encoding directly:

```
  const cert_der = req.connection.getPeerCertificate().raw;
  console.log(cert_der);
```

In general, having the DER encoding should be sufficient. However, if you need the PEM encoding, you can construct it by applying the base64 encoding to the DER encoding:

```
const os = require('os');

function der_to_pem(der) {
  const header = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----';
  const footer = '-----END CERTIFICATE-----';

  return [header, der.toString('base64'), footer].join(os.EOL);
}
```

You could then use this helper function to obtain the PEM encoding of the client certificate:

```
  const cert_der = req.connection.getPeerCertificate().raw;
  console.log(der_to_pem(cert_der));
```